# Xcode 3.2.5 with IOS SDK 4.2 download

Tags: ios, xcode

Where can i download the Xcode 3.2.5 with IOS SDK 4.2 in apple developer portal.Xcode 4 and xcode 3.2.6 only available there.

Need help on this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can download it from https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/Developer_Tools/xcode_3.2.6_and_ios_sdk_4.3__final/xcode_3.2.6_and_ios_sdk_4.3.dmg

Xcode 3.2.6 and iOS 4.3

Xcode 3.2.5 isn't available on Apple portal.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it from apple.  Check this page for old releases:

http://connect.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MemberSite.woa/wo/4.1.17.2.1.3.3.1.0.1.1.0.3.3.3.3.1