# mpi4py installation in mac

Tags: python, mpi, openmpi

I'm trying to install mpi4py on mac, but I've faced with below error:

Searching for mpi4py

```
Best match: mpi4py 1.2.2 
Downloading http://mpi4py.googlecode.com/files/mpi4py-1.2.2.tar.gz 
Processing mpi4py-1.2.2.tar.gz 
Running mpi4py-1.2.2/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-HNJHvI/mpi4py-1.2.2/egg-dist-tmp-eL_Hte 
Compiling with an SDK that doesn't seem to exist: /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk Please check your Xcode installation
_configtest.c:1:20: error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
error: Setup script exited with error: Cannot compile/link MPI programs. Check your configuration!!!
```

Note that I installed openmpi before.

Any body knows what's the solution?

Comment: have you followed these instructions? http://mpi4py.scipy.org/docs/usrman/appendix.html#mac-os-x-and-universal-sdk-python-builds

Answer (score 0):

Error message is pretty clear, it looks for MacOSX10.5.sdk, you have to install it from XCode (it's in the installer options).

To install it try the following:

- [download XCode 3.2.6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6339982/11343)
- open the meta package (right clik-> show bundle content)
- install OSX-10.5.pkg

**EDIT before doing this painful stuff you might want to read [Mac OS X and Universal/SDK Python builds](http://mpi4py.scipy.org/docs/usrman/appendix.html#mac-os-x-and-universal-sdk-python-builds)**

Comment: I've checked my sdk folder and I have version 6 and 7 but not version 5. How can I add it?